# SAGA Point Statistics for Polygons

Tags: qgis-3, layers, point, error, saga

I am running [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) 3.10 on a MAC using Catalina (and I also tried on QGIS 3.4) and tried to run [SAGA](http://www.saga-gis.org/) Point Statistics for Polygons. Every time I run it I get an error with it trying to create the layer.

I have:
a. taken all the spaces out of names
b. Tried almost every possible directory

But nothing works.

Ideas?

Here's the log:

```
QGIS version: 3.10.5-A Coruña
QGIS code revision: 984615fe1e
Qt version: 5.12.3
GDAL version: 2.4.1
GEOS version: 3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.2 b55d2125
PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Point statistics for polygons' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'AVG ' : False, 'DEV ' : False, 'FIELDS' : 'Intake Total', 'FIELD_NAME' : 0, 'MAX ' : False, 'MIN ' : False, 'NUM ' : True, 'POINTS' : 'file:///Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/The%20Institute/Projects/Life%20of%20Riley/Shelter%20intake%20models/Master%20Data%20for%20Project/shelter/sac%20pacfa%20va%20%20bf%20combined%20may%207.csv?type=csv&detectTypes=yes&xField=Lon&yField=Lat&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no', 'POLYGONS' : '/Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/The Institute/Projects/Life of Riley/Shelter intake models/Master Data for Project/demographic data/County data joined with demo.shp|layername=County data joined with demo', 'STATISTICS' : '/Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/test.shp', 'SUM ' : True, 'VAR ' : False }

shapes_polygons "Point Statistics for Polygons" -POINTS "/private/var/folders/q5/dn3prvx1279894gq00wjmzh80000gn/T/processing_e17dc0d3ac7d452cbe81b35ece4ea034/6df0debf79ed47f4b6330c885ed98bb9/POINTS.shp" -POLYGONS "/Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/The Institute/Projects/Life of Riley/Shelter intake models/Master Data for Project/demographic data/County data joined with demo.shp" -FIELDS "Intake Total" -FIELD_NAME 0 -SUM true -AVG false -VAR false -DEV false -MIN false -MAX false -NUM true -STATISTICS "/Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/test.shp"
Error: no attributes in selection
Error: executing tool [Point Statistics for Polygons]
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2

____________________________
library path: /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/aaa/
library name: libshapes_polygons
library : Polygons
tool : Point Statistics for Polygons
author : V. Olaya, O. Conrad (c) 2005, 2010
____________________________

Load shapes: /private/var/folders/q5/dn3prvx1279894gq00wjmzh80000gn/T/processing_e17dc0d3ac7d452cbe81b35ece4ea034/6df0debf79ed47f4b6330c885ed98bb9/POINTS.shp...


Load shapes: /Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/The Institute/Projects/Life of Riley/Shelter intake models/Master Data for Project/demographic data/County data joined with demo.shp...




Parameters


Points: POINTS
Attributes: <no attributes>
Polygons: County data joined with demo
Statistics: Statistics
Sum: yes
Mean: no
Variance: no
Deviation: no
Minimum: no
Maximum: no
Count: yes
Field Naming: variable type + original name

Execution completed in 3.99 seconds
Results:
{'STATISTICS': '/Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/test.shp'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>/Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/test.shp</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
QGIS version: 3.10.5-A Coruña
QGIS code revision: 984615fe1e
Qt version: 5.12.3
GDAL version: 2.4.1
GEOS version: 3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.2 b55d2125
PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Point statistics for polygons' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'AVG ' : False, 'DEV ' : False, 'FIELDS' : 'Intake Total', 'FIELD_NAME' : 0, 'MAX ' : False, 'MIN ' : False, 'NUM ' : True, 'POINTS' : 'file:///Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/The%20Institute/Projects/Life%20of%20Riley/Shelter%20intake%20models/Master%20Data%20for%20Project/shelter/sac%20pacfa%20va%20%20bf%20combined%20may%207.csv?type=csv&detectTypes=yes&xField=Lon&yField=Lat&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no', 'POLYGONS' : '/Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/The Institute/Projects/Life of Riley/Shelter intake models/Master Data for Project/demographic data/County data joined with demo.shp|layername=County data joined with demo', 'STATISTICS' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'SUM ' : True, 'VAR ' : False }

shapes_polygons "Point Statistics for Polygons" -POINTS "/private/var/folders/q5/dn3prvx1279894gq00wjmzh80000gn/T/processing_e17dc0d3ac7d452cbe81b35ece4ea034/30f1041231c54c7a81659facd65cf697/POINTS.shp" -POLYGONS "/Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/The Institute/Projects/Life of Riley/Shelter intake models/Master Data for Project/demographic data/County data joined with demo.shp" -FIELDS "Intake Total" -FIELD_NAME 0 -SUM true -AVG false -VAR false -DEV false -MIN false -MAX false -NUM true -STATISTICS "/private/var/folders/q5/dn3prvx1279894gq00wjmzh80000gn/T/processing_e17dc0d3ac7d452cbe81b35ece4ea034/6cc1dba2f8064dc48323ca2350ce3e48/STATISTICS.shp"
Error: no attributes in selection
Error: executing tool [Point Statistics for Polygons]
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2

____________________________
library path: /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/aaa/
library name: libshapes_polygons
library : Polygons
tool : Point Statistics for Polygons
author : V. Olaya, O. Conrad (c) 2005, 2010
____________________________

Load shapes: /private/var/folders/q5/dn3prvx1279894gq00wjmzh80000gn/T/processing_e17dc0d3ac7d452cbe81b35ece4ea034/30f1041231c54c7a81659facd65cf697/POINTS.shp...


Load shapes: /Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/The Institute/Projects/Life of Riley/Shelter intake models/Master Data for Project/demographic data/County data joined with demo.shp...




Parameters


Points: POINTS
Attributes: <no attributes>
Polygons: County data joined with demo
Statistics: Statistics
Sum: yes
Mean: no
Variance: no
Deviation: no
Minimum: no
Maximum: no
Count: yes
Field Naming: variable type + original name

Execution completed in 4.32 seconds
Results:
{'STATISTICS': '/private/var/folders/q5/dn3prvx1279894gq00wjmzh80000gn/T/processing_e17dc0d3ac7d452cbe81b35ece4ea034/6cc1dba2f8064dc48323ca2350ce3e48/STATISTICS.shp'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>/private/var/folders/q5/dn3prvx1279894gq00wjmzh80000gn/T/processing_e17dc0d3ac7d452cbe81b35ece4ea034/6cc1dba2f8064dc48323ca2350ce3e48/STATISTICS.shp</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
QGIS version: 3.10.5-A Coruña
QGIS code revision: 984615fe1e
Qt version: 5.12.3
GDAL version: 2.4.1
GEOS version: 3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.2 b55d2125
PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Point statistics for polygons' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'AVG ' : False, 'DEV ' : False, 'FIELDS' : 'Intake Total', 'FIELD_NAME' : 0, 'MAX ' : False, 'MIN ' : False, 'NUM ' : True, 'POINTS' : 'file:///Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/The%20Institute/Projects/Life%20of%20Riley/Shelter%20intake%20models/Master%20Data%20for%20Project/shelter/sac%20pacfa%20va%20%20bf%20combined%20may%207.csv?type=csv&detectTypes=yes&xField=Lon&yField=Lat&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no', 'POLYGONS' : '/Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/The Institute/Projects/Life of Riley/Shelter intake models/Master Data for Project/demographic data/County data joined with demo.shp|layername=County data joined with demo', 'STATISTICS' : '/Users/rogerhaston/Documents/test.shp', 'SUM ' : True, 'VAR ' : False }

shapes_polygons "Point Statistics for Polygons" -POINTS "/private/var/folders/q5/dn3prvx1279894gq00wjmzh80000gn/T/processing_e17dc0d3ac7d452cbe81b35ece4ea034/570e08116b2a42eba7956e09d8a26674/POINTS.shp" -POLYGONS "/Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/The Institute/Projects/Life of Riley/Shelter intake models/Master Data for Project/demographic data/County data joined with demo.shp" -FIELDS "Intake Total" -FIELD_NAME 0 -SUM true -AVG false -VAR false -DEV false -MIN false -MAX false -NUM true -STATISTICS "/Users/rogerhaston/Documents/test.shp"
Error: no attributes in selection
Error: executing tool [Point Statistics for Polygons]
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2

____________________________
library path: /Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Resources/aaa/
library name: libshapes_polygons
library : Polygons
tool : Point Statistics for Polygons
author : V. Olaya, O. Conrad (c) 2005, 2010
____________________________

Load shapes: /private/var/folders/q5/dn3prvx1279894gq00wjmzh80000gn/T/processing_e17dc0d3ac7d452cbe81b35ece4ea034/570e08116b2a42eba7956e09d8a26674/POINTS.shp...


Load shapes: /Users/rogerhaston/Dropbox/The Institute/Projects/Life of Riley/Shelter intake models/Master Data for Project/demographic data/County data joined with demo.shp...




Parameters


Points: POINTS
Attributes: <no attributes>
Polygons: County data joined with demo
Statistics: Statistics
Sum: yes
Mean: no
Variance: no
Deviation: no
Minimum: no
Maximum: no
Count: yes
Field Naming: variable type + original name

Execution completed in 4.50 seconds
Results:
{'STATISTICS': '/Users/rogerhaston/Documents/test.shp'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>/Users/rogerhaston/Documents/test.shp</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my two cents: You likely have imported a CSV data into QGIS through *Add Delimited Layer* and been trying to run the statistics tool on it. Many geoprocessing tools do not work properly on CSV layer.

Export the POINTS layer as a new shapefile, and resume working on the shapefile. (Also pay attention to the field name and datatype).

---

TLDR part:

First, I checked the error message `Error: no attributes in selection`, then noticed the  attribute field name `Intake Total` was too long for a shapefile (length <= 10).

Then, looking up the input parameters, found there was *type=csv*; 
 `'POINTS' : 'file:///Users/.../sac%20pacfa%20va%20%20bf%20combined%20may%207.csv?type=csv&detectTypes=yes&xField=Lon&yField=Lat&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no'`